# NSLocalizedString load key return key in iOS 13.2(other iOS version working fine why?)

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

i have 15 language files in Localizable.strings
- configure the key / value on the English or others Like:

codes:

```
NSLog(@"--->test1-%@-",NSLocalizedString(@"stringtest", nil));
NSLog(@"--->test2-%@-",NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"stringtest",@"Localizable", nil));
```

iOS 13.2 RESULT:

2019-10-31 18:45:10.835212+0800 APPNAME[2690:370808] --->test1-stringtest-

2019-10-31 18:45:10.835275+0800 APPNAME[2690:370808] --->test2-stringtest-

iOS 12.4.1 / 13.1 RESULT:

2019-10-31 18:37:54.750426+0800 APPNAME [1761:1544978] --->test1-Ttttt11-

2019-10-31 18:37:54.750689+0800 APPNAME [1761:1544978] --->test2-Ttttt11-

did something wrong? any suggest will be great, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did actions:

Duplicate a new TARGET, and one by one check for Info's plist and settings infos(with another project working will)

and i find the key in the Info's plist:

KEY: "Localization native development region", did set an invalid string(to long string) like: @"i did it but i don't remenber, and balabala-balabala-balabala-balabala"